# Validate individual field in Phoenix/Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my phoenix app I need to validate a single field by its name. I need this because I have the update via ajax mechanism where I edit/update only a single field at a time.

How can I do that? That is, given a field name, how can I validate **that and only that single field**? Note that the value of the field might be valid even when it's  empty depending on my validation logic.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your question? Do you mean a form field or something else? Please include any relevant code with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think i understood your question correctly.

Let us assume you have a **user** model with fields *name, age, experience* and whenever you want to ***update/edit*** you will send a user_id and the change.

In update method, we will get the **user** by *user_id* and put this change and validate the changeset *(Eg: User.changeset(Repo.get(User, user_id), input_change))*. As no change in other fields, literally you are validating ***only one field***

So you can put all your validation in your changeset itself

```
def changeset(model, params) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> validate_age
  |> validate_experience
  |> validate_name
end
```